# Hair isn't able to be combed

Tags: mesh, particles, hair, vertex-groups

I'm trying to use different colours of hair on a single mesh, and I am using vertex groups to achieve this. When I set the hair to the 'beige' vertex group I am unable to comb it, even though I did the exact same thing for the 'brown' vertex group.[Here is the blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v29j5kyrwfab6av/dog.blend?dl=0)